# ¿Cómo resolver esto? tools:replace=android:configChanges

Tags: android, android-studio

Mi archivo manifiesto

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
   <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.HistoryByMonth"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history_by_month"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.HistoryMonthView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history_month_view"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
      </activity>

    <activity
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|
         orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|uiMode|smallestScreenSize" />
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

  </application>
   </manifest>
```

Este el error que se presenta cuando compilo la aplicación:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute 
  activity#com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity@configChanges value=(keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|uiMode|smallestScreenSize) from AndroidManifest.xml:112:13-122
is also present at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:11.0.4] AndroidManifest.xml:25:72-181 value=(keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:configChanges"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:110:7-115:13 to override.
```

Answer (score 0):

Asegura de agregar correctamente la propiedad `android:configChanges` y su valor:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|uiMode|smallestScreenSize"
```

y agrega también :

```
tools:replace="android:configChanges"
```

para esto tendrás que agregar el namespace: `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

---

De acuerdo a tu `AndroidManifest.xml` la configuración de la `Activity` debería realizarse de esta forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            package="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager"
           android:versionCode="1"
           android:versionName="1.0" >    

        ...
        ...

        <activity
             tools:replace="android:configChanges"
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|uiMode|smallestScreenSize" />

     ...
     ...
```

Comment: Hermano te agradecería si me ayudas a compilarlo te agradecería muchísimo este es el link del proyecto: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SS2aSOX83gAN243XoqRvbIVodNlaJTS0/view]

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: @user3802081 lo que escribí en mi respuesta no soluciona el problema especificado en la pregunta.?

Comment: Gracias por responder lo que me sugeriste sí funcionó pero ahora me salen estos errores podrías indicarme que podría ser? son los que están en la imagen de arriba.

Comment: @user3802081 es un error diferente en tu archivo build.gradle debes cambiar "compile" por "implementation"