# Errores al compilar aplicación en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas estoy recibiendo los errores que se encuentran en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi manifest:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" >
</uses-feature>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.DailyExpence"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.Home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.Add_Expences"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_transaction"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.History"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.Settings"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.Edit_Category"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit__category"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.History_List"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history__list"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.Edit_Expense"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit__expense"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.Edit_Paymode"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit__paymode"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.History_All"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history__all"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.ReminderActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reminder"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.MySimpleNotification"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reminder"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.TransactionNotification"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reminder"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.NotifyService" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.HistoryByMonth"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history_by_month"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.HistoryMonthView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history_month_view"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

  <activity
      tools:replace="android:configChanges"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|uiMode|smallestScreenSize" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

Comment: prueba con `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'`

Comment: me parece que esta pregunta tiene relación con esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157526/c%C3%B3mo-resolver-esto-toolsreplace-androidconfigchanges/157532#157532

Answer (score 2):

Primero reemplazar en el archivo `build.gradle` las etiquetas que dicen `compile` por `implementation`, ya que con la nueva actualización del `gradle` compile quedo obsoleto.

Para verificar el otro problema verifique en el archivo string que se encuentra los valores que se muestran con **error** y que el `R`.

Este configurado en el proyecto. (si `R` no esta configurado deshabilite la librería `appcompactv7` y vuelva a **habilitar**)

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente para solucionar el `warning`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debes reemplazar dentro de tu `build.gradle`, `compile` por `implementation`, esto porque la versión de gradle marca como obsoleto el uso de  `compile`, como ejemplo:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

cambiar a :

```
implementation  fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

ahora con respecto a el error:

> "resource android:style/TextAppareance.Material not found"

veo que tienes definido`android:targetSdkVersion="17"`,

```
   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

considera usar un `android:targetSdkVersion` mas actual para que tu aplicación pueda funcionar correctamente en nuevas versiones de OS:

Comment: `android:targetSdkVersion="27"` He modificado tal cual pero aún sigue saliendo el error android:style  not found

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que vallas a tu proyecto y elimines la carpeta  .gradle aveces tiene problemas al compilar y otra cosa

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.*'
```

para la ultima version

Comment: En un proyecto no se crea una carperta ".build.gradle", te refieres a "build"?

Comment: es una carpeta que se se llama .gradle con el  punto